# Time complexity of greedy algorithm to find a maximal independent set of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, greedy, independent-set

A simple greedy algorithm to find a maximal independent set, I think it will take O(n) time since no vertex will be visited more than twice. Why wiki said it would take O(m) time?

```
Greedy(G)
while G is not empty (visited V in an arbitrary order)
    mark v as IS and v's neighbors as Non-IS
return all IS vertices
```

Comment: could you pls provide a link to the wiki's page?

Comment: What is `m` in your example?

Comment: Sorry, this is the web link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set, see the sequential algorithm.

Comment: m denotes the number of edges and n denotes the number of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it on K<sub>n/2,n/2</sub>, the neighbors on the side not chosen each get marked as non-IS n/2 times.